# dev certificate not trusted .NET CORE API running on kestrel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ubuntu, ssl, kestrel-http-server

I am having trouble connecting to my API from my browser. I am assuming this message may have something to do with it but I cannot resolve it. I went to the site it told me to and tried running all the commands and got no errors, but when I restart the kestrel service the certificate not trusted warning is still present.

```
Mar 17 03:42:39 ip-172-31-34-40 dotnet-web-app[663782]: warn: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[8] Mar 17 03:42:39 ip-172-31-34-40 dotnet-web-app[663782]:       
The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/https-trust-dev-cert. 
Mar 17 03:42:39 ip-172-31-34-40 dotnet-web-app[663782]: 
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14] 
Mar 17 03:42:39 ip-172-31-34-40 dotnet-web-app[663782]:       
Now listening on: https://localhost:7040 Mar 17 03:42:39 ip-172-31-34-40 dotnet-web-app[663782]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

I am on ubuntu 22.04 and using dotnet 8.0 if that helps.

Comment: For Ubuntu and/or Firefox you need special instructions, pointed out in the link in the error message and require manual steps. The `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` is for windows and mac only. For linux you need to run `dotnet dev-certs https` and manual steps to install the newly created certificate in your store and additional steps fore Firefox and other special browser which don't use the OS' cert store

Comment: Like the other comment indicates, you should read an article, which is clearly in the warning itself.

Comment: the issue is i read the article and followed all the instructions for troubleshooting to no avail, which is clearly in the post itself.

Comment: Then why not show a full screen shot? We need to see the error message and the address bar of that browser.